# Google chart API - continuous hAxis as Date - year end is next beginning?

Tags: javascript, date, charts, google-visualization

I've made a custom data source selector for the [Google Chart Editor](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_charteditor) which has worked out wonderfully, but I'm running into an annoying little problem with the way the dates are represented on the [continuous](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#Discrete_vs_Continuous) major axis of type date. For some reason, giving **a date at the end of the year** (e.g. `new Date(2014,11,31,0,0,0)`) **gets labelled as the next year**.

Here's a [JSFiddle that describes the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/JabberWakky/7fgz0g66/). I know I could just use a discrete axis and pass a string representation of the year, but my data source selector allows selecting a different interval (i.e. daily, monthly, weekly yearly) and a continuous axis is best for this.

Does anyone know why this happens, and is there a way to adjust how the API chooses labels for a continuous date axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's interesting how phrasing a question for others can make one think of an answer. I decided to try specifying the `options.hAxis.ticks` and although I pass the same dates, it does change the hAxis labels to what I expect.

[See the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JabberWakky/7fgz0g66/3/)

It's not the best solution, since I would rather have the hAxis ticks match the nearest data point, but it is functional.

Here are the options that I specified:

```
   var options = {
        title: 'Total Sales Value Per Year',
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Year End',
            ticks: [ 
                new Date(2010,11,31,0,0,0), 
                new Date(2011,11,31,0,0,0), 
                new Date(2012,11,31,0,0,0), 
                new Date(2013,11,31,0,0,0), 
                new Date(2014,11,31,0,0,0) 
            ]
        }
    };
```